# Bootstrap change position of columns and splitting them

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

So have this problem and didn't really find a solution to solve it.
I have this initial design when the screen is large:

[image: Initial layout big screen]

And when the screen is resized to a small screen I want to have the following
[image]

So It's actually a problem with the first one to have to logo as big as the Title and text together, and then move the title above the logo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is all about positioning.

1. Title
2. logo
3. text

Make a parent div with class row.

Then inside, create your title first with class `col-md-6 col-xs-12 pull-right`.  This will cause the title to float right.  Do the same with the text.

The logo should get the same classes, but `pull-left` instead of `pull-right`.  This will cause it to float left.

But on mobile all will be below each other.

Check out the fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/80r028jq/1/